# Angular 8 clearing localStorage on logout

Tags: angular, oauth

I am using `localStorage` for auth token. 
to save it I am using `localStorage.setItem('token','value')` and to remove it I am using `localStorage.clear()` and both working fine. But when I logged in with another user the service constructor is till sending the previous token which is actually deleted from `localStorage()`. 
service constructor is below

```
  token: string;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('eq_user'));
    if ( user ) {
      this.token = user.access_token;
    }
  }
```

Login:

```
login() {
  this.auth.login(data).subscribe((response: UserToken) => {
    localStorage.setItem('eq_user', JSON.stringify(response));
    this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
  },
  error => {
    this.error = true;
    this.errorMsg = error.message;
  }
}
```

Logout

```
onLogout() {
    localStorage.removeItem('eq_user');
    localStorage.clear();
    this.authService.logout().subscribe( s => {
        this.route.navigate(['login']);
   });
  }
```

following is link identical to my issue.

[https://stackblitz.com/](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wabtj6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

First click on `setValue` and then click on A from Component and A from Service, on first time it will take the correct value. But when you click again on setValue and then click on the other two buttons the Component button return fresh value but the service is not returning the fresh values.

Comment: new token is sent when page is reloaded.

Comment: according to your code, the service is storing the token from local storage it its property field. so you need to clear that property of your service.

Comment: Please provide the code where you set and remove the token from local storage?

Comment: I have edit the question and added the login and logout functions

Comment: @DPro I am not getting how to clear a service property? can you guide a little!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After spending almost a day how to send the fresh token I come up with the solution that It can be easily done by using `HttpInterceptor`, if you define a custom interceptor for headers then you don't need to look for token in your service, the interceptor will add the Bearer TOKEN to all http requrest.

[Click here for more details](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor)

Comment: export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor{ intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>>{const idToken = localStorage.getItem("jwtToken");

        if (idToken) {
            const cloned = req.clone({
                headers: req.headers.set("Authorization",
                    "Bearer " + idToken)
            });

            return next.handle(cloned);
        }
        else {
            return next.handle(req);
        }}

Comment: add the provide: HTTP_INTERE3CEPTOR, useClass:AuthInterceptor as a provider in app.module.ts

Answer (score 1):

See, angular services are singleton services when declared in root. So your constructor will be called just once and at that time it stores the token. So when you are clearing the localstorage you have to clear the variable.
You can create a clear function in your service to clear the token variable. And call that function when you logout.

Comment: let say I am on dashboard module and I click on logout, and then login with another account, in this case the dashboard module has the previous token but when I click on another module route it has new token, I am not getting how to handle it.

Comment: Can you recreate the issue on stackblitz?

Comment: I have re-created identical issue on stackblitz, link and case scenario is available in the question.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor of a singleton service is called only once that is during loading of the app. I assume your service is singleton. So the logic written inside the constructor will not execute more than once. You have to set the token inside login method also, which runs every time a user login. Also remove the token when user logout.

```
login() {
    this.auth.login(data).subscribe((response: UserToken) => {
      this.token = response.access_token;
      localStorage.setItem('eq_user', JSON.stringify(response));
      this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
    },
    error => {
      this.error = true;
      this.errorMsg = error.message;
    }
  }


onLogout() {
    this.token = null;
    localStorage.removeItem('eq_user');
    localStorage.clear();
    this.authService.logout().subscribe( s => {
        this.route.navigate(['login']);
   });
  }
```

I have updated your example stackblitz code with the changes I mentioned above - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cz5huh

Comment: result is still the same. I did not see any change to the code except adding `AuthService` in `app.module.ts` providers